# BreezeJS with a NodeJS API (not directly to MongoDB)

Tags: node.js, breeze

I'm researching BreezeJS for a big upcoming project.

Our goal is a offline first web app.

But here is what I can't fully understand (and would take to much time to test) - Does BreezeJS allow for the backend to be a REST API (built with NodeJS and Express)?

We need this because we don't want to simply sync to a remote DB (in our case Mongo), but use a remote REST API so that we can embed some business logic. Things like workflow triggering on a POST to a particular entity.

Is this possible with BreezeJS? If not what would be a good option?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly possible, simply take the breeze-mongo server implementation and strip out the mongo specific code. This should be fairly straight forward, express and mongo are pretty well separated in the code.

That said, you would lose or have to rewrite much of the server side code that converts an OData query string into a mongo query, but if you are going pure 'REST' you probably don't want that anyway.

You would have to do something similar on the save/POST side, but this is presumably something you are already familiar with.

Comment: i would be interested in a blog post or documentation section which highlights the benefits of using breeze with pure REST(no IQueryables, no saveChanges(..)). I for myself know a few of them but i'm sure that a lot of potential breeze users don't.

Comment: Thanks @JayTraband, I'll look into it. I'm going to leave this open for now to see if any other answers appear, but I'll give you the answer if I get this to work